# PIG Latin : While loading how to discard the first line in any file?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I've been using PIG since sometime and wanted to know how to not consider the first line while loading a file. I've a file which has headers. So I should ignore the first line and go to the next line to do the processing on the date columns and all. How to go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have pig version 0.11 you could try this:

```
input_file = load 'input' USING PigStorage(',') as (row1:chararay, row2:chararray);

ranked = rank input_file;

NoHeader = Filter ranked by (rank_input_file > 1);

New_input_file = foreach NoHeader generate row1, row2;
```

The New_input_file should have your data without the header. note that the rank operator is new to pig 0.11, so this will not work with earlier versions.

EDIT: note this solution only works with a single file, if you are instead loading a directory try something else instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I still don't understand what is rank_input_file relation in the filter condition.

Comment: @Dev the Rank operator gererates a column of unique numbers, forming another column. The name of this column is by default set to rank_<input dataset name>. because I ranked a set named input_file the column that contains the ranking numbers is called rank_input_file by default. given that the rank starts at one ane increases by default the header row will have rank one. filtering by rank_input_file > 1 will get every row except the header.

Comment: I like that this is easily adjustable to work with multi header lines. Is there a straigtforward way to extend this to work with multiple files?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin no. Not that I know of.

Answer (score 2):

The given solution will work well if you just load in 1 file. However, if you load in all files in a directory (which is also possible by simply making sure that input is a directory path), the given solution will only cut off the top for the first file.

For removing the header in each file, you will probably want to use [CSVExcelStorage](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html)

```
my_input = load 'inputfileordir' USING CSVExcelStorage(',', 'default', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER')
```